# Reading images (jpeg) from a zipped folder

Tags: r, zip, jpeg

I have a following folder structure in a zipped file "imgs.zip"

```
names.files <- unzip("imgs.zip","test",list=TRUE)
names.files$Name[3]
[1] "test/img_10.jpg"
```

Using the following code to read the image

```
readJPEG(unz("imgs.zip",names.files$Name[3]))
```

I get the error message

> Error in path.expand(source) : invalid 'path' argument

I tried searching for reading images from a zipped folder in R but all in vain so far.

Comment: What is the working directory? i.e. `getwd()` You may need to use `paste` to get the correct path. i.e. `paste("C:\some\file\path", names.files$Name[3], sep="\")` or so

Comment: @akrun The zip file ```imgs.zip``` is located in the working directory.

Comment: As the output of `names.files$Name[3]` is `"test/img_10.jpg"`, you may need to specify the path correctly

Comment: @akrun But I thought that in ```unz(description, filename, open = "", encoding = getOption("encoding"))``` the filename is the name of the file within the zip file. The full file path would be ```"C:/Project/imgs.zip/test/img_10.jpg"```. And I want to read the image w/o unzipping imgs.zip.

Comment: If you give the full path, does it work?

Comment: @akrun I tried this ```readJPEG(unz("imgs.zip",paste(getwd(), names.files$Name[3], sep="/")))``` but I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unzip` for both extracting the file names and for reading the files:

```
library(jpeg)
# Select your Zip file or replace file.choose() with exact path
zippath <- file.choose() 
names.files <- unzip(zippath, list=TRUE)
readJPEG(unzip(zippath, names.files$Name[3]))
```

No need to use `paste`.

Comment: I wonder why a connection to the source cannot be used by ```readJPEG``` function.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can read a zipped image file through `unz`. In short, `readJPEG` is looking for a filepath, not a connection, which is what `unz` gives you.

Look at the kind of output it gives you:

```
> test <- (unz("figure.zip", names.files$Name[3]))
> test
                    description                           class                            mode                            text 
"figure.zip:figure/age_all.png"                           "unz"                             "r"                          "text" 
                         opened                        can read                       can write 
                       "closed"                           "yes"                           "yes" 
> str(test)
Classes 'unz', 'connection'  atomic [1:1] 6
  ..- attr(*, "conn_id")=<externalptr>
```

readJPEG is expecting a filepath to an uncompressed image, not whatever this `unz` connection is. Specifically, this is where it's failing:

```
source <- path.expand(source)
```

Where source in your case is the output of `unz`.